# Can not implicitly convert type 'System.Colections.Generic.IEnuerable<product>' to 'product'. An explicit conversion exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generic-exception

I am new to asp.net MVC. i am getting the following the error while trying to assign :

**Can not implicitly  convert type 'System.Colections.Generic.IEnuerable' to 'product'. An explicit conversion exist**

My Code is

```
ILookup<string,product> productList = Model.ToLookup(x=>x.parentId,x=>x);
IEnumerable<string> roots =Model.Select(x=>x.parentId).Except(Model.Select(x=>x.id));
foreach(var id in roots){
    product pr = productList[id].Select(item => item);//Error here

}
```

where product is a class with properties

```
int paretId;int id;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Obviously `Select(item => item)` causing exception because it selects all items of `productList` as `IEnumerable` and you're tried to convert it as `product`. Try using `Select` with a `product` class property as target (e.g. `Select(item => item.something)`).

Comment: At that point it will return only that value, right?

Comment: How can i get the product instance instead?

Comment: Right. The `Select` method should be modified to return a `product` instead of returning entire `productList` members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
product pr = productList[id].Select(item => item);
```

to

```
product pr = productList[id].Select(item => item).First();
```

or, more simply,

```
product pr = productList[id];
```

Whenever write code like this: `something.Select(t=>t)` , it should remove the `Select` statement and become `something`

Comment: It Worked.. Thanks a lot!